# Isometry induced on the Grassmannian of planes to the tangent space

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and assume that $G$ acts isometrically and effectively on $M$. We can then split $TM = \mathcal V\oplus \mathcal H$ globally, though it not does not need to furnish a bundle decomposition, where $\mathcal V_x$ is identified with the tangent space to the orbit through $x\in M$.

Let $Gr_{2}(T_xM)$ be the Grasmannian of two planes defined out of $T_xM$. My questions are:

> $(i)$ is there a defined action of $G$ on $Gr_2(T_xM)$ induced by the $G$ action on $M$? This seems to be the case whenever $x$ is a fixed point, so my guess is that only the isotropy group at $x\in M$ defines such an action. Indeed, if $G_x$ denotes the isotropy group at $x$ one defines $d\rho : G_x \rightarrow \mathcal L(T_xM,T_xM)$  by
> $d\rho(g)(\bar X) := d\mu_g(X)$ where $\mu : G\times M \rightarrow M$ denotes the $G$-action. Hence, the corresponding action on $Gr_2(T_xM)$ should be $(g \in G_x,\bar X\wedge \bar Y \in G_2(T_xM)) \mapsto d\rho(g)\bar X\wedge d\rho(g)\bar Y. $
>
> $(ii)$ related to question $(i)$ for which groups it holds that the induced action preserves the $\mathcal V_x\oplus \mathcal H_x$ decomposition? Namely, for a plane $X\wedge V$ with $X\in \cal H_x, V\in \mathcal V_x$ there is an isometry mapping $X\wedge V$ in a plane of the same form?